# Numerical Integration - Method of Undetermined Coefficients.

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I was reading about Numerical Integration using the Method of Undetermined Coefficients.

The definition and thought process I came across was :

- $f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree m : $a_0 + a_1x+a_2x^2+ \dots +a_mx^m$
- We will attempt to express $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \,dx$ as a linear combination of **n** values of $f(x)$ like this : $$\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \,dx = w_0f(x_0) +w_1f(x_1)+ \dots +w_nf(x_n)$$

Where ***I guess*** that $x_0 = a$ and $x_n = b$

So the error will be in the form : $$E=\int_{x_0}^{x_n} f(x)  \,dx \space - \sum_{i=0}^{i=n}w_if(x_i) 
 $$ $$E=\int_{x_0}^{x_n} a_0 + a_1x+a_2x^2+ \dots +a_mx^m \,dx \space - \sum_{i=0}^{i=n}w_i(a_0 + a_1x_i+a_2x_i^2+ \dots +a_mx_i^m)$$

$$E=\int_{x_0}^{x_n} a_0 \,dx+\int_{x_0}^{x_n} a_1 x\,dx+ \dots + \int_{x_0}^{x_n} a_m x^m \,dx \space - \sum_{i=0}^{i=n}w_i(a_0 + a_1x_i+ \dots +a_mx_i^m)$$ $$\dots$$

$$E = a_0[\int_{x_0}^{x_n} 1 \,dx \space - \sum_{i=0}^{i=n}w_i] + a_1[\int_{x_0}^{x_n} x \,dx \space - \sum_{i=0}^{i=n}w_ix_i] + \dots + a_m[\int_{x_0}^{x_n} x^m \,dx \space - \sum_{i=0}^{i=n}w_ix^m] $$
$$E=a_0E(x^0)+a_1E(x^1)+a_2E(x^2)+\dots+a_mE(x^m)$$

So we want our attempt to be precise and we demand each term $E(x^i)=0$ which makes sense to me.

Then there was that one example that I struggle to understand :

- Given that $n=1$ which ***I guess*** means we will express $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \,dx$ as a linear combination of **2** values of $f(x)$
- $\int_{x_0}^{x_1} f(x) \,dx=w_0f(x_0)+w_1f(x_1)$ where $x_0 = a$ , $x_1 = b$ and $h = x_1 - x_0$

Stage (1) of the solution :

1. Given that $f(x)=1$
2. $A_1$ =  $\int_{x_0}^{x_1} f(x) \,dx = w_0f(x_0)+w_1f(x_1) = w_0 + w_1$
3. $B_1$ =  $\int_{x_0}^{x_1} x^0 \,dx = x_1 - x_0 = h$
4. We demand that $A_1 = B_1$ and so $w_0 + w_1 = h$

Stage (2) of the solution :

5. Given that $f(x)=x$
6. $A_2$ =  $\int_{x_0}^{x_1} f(x) \,dx = w_0f(x_0)+w_1f(x_1) = w_0x_0 + w_1x_1$
7. $B_2$ =  $\int_{x_0}^{x_1} x^1 \,dx = \frac{x^2_1- x^2_0}{2}$
8. We demand that $A_2 = B_2$ and so $w_0x_0 + w_1x_1 = \frac{h*(x_1 + x_0)}{2}$

From (4) and (8) we finally get the Trapezoidal rule where :

- $w_0=w_1=\frac{h}{2}$
- $\int_{x_0}^{x_1} f(x) \,dx=\frac{h}{2}[f(x_0)+f(x_1)]$

Questions :

- In the process above is the degree m of $f(x)$ known?
- Why does the writer state in steps (1) and (5) that $f(x)=1$ and $f(x)=x$ ? Shouldn't $f(x)$ be a **standard**  polynomial ?
- Demanding the terms $E(x^0)$ and $E(x^1)$ to be equal to $0$ is equivalent, isn't it?
- Given that we use 2 values of $f(x)$ why do we just take the first 2 $E(x^i)$ terms and not up to $E(x^m)$ ? I guess it has to do with the fact that we only have 2 unknown coefficients $w_0$ and $w_1$ so 2 equations is just fine.

**Update (1)** :

I was trying to figure out the relationship between $n$ and $m$ and I think it comes down to 2 cases where :

1. $n = m$
2. $n < m$

In case 1 you can indeed go up to $m$ when it comes to the $E(x^i)=0$ condition as you can approach $f(x)$ using a polynomial of $n$ degree which will be itself and the error will be equal to $0$.

In case 2 I think you can only go up to the $n$ term when it comes to the $E(x^i)=0$ condition because you can only approach $f(x)$ by a polynomial of degree $n$ where in this case some error will exist but it will be minimized.

**Update (2)** :

When it comes to the questions (1) and (5) ***I think*** it has to do with the application of **Update (1)** on each polynomial term $x^i$ of $f(x)$ and not for the whole $f$ itself. However the way I approached this in these 2 updates is by approximating $f(x)$ which is a polynomial by using a polynomial and a new question has arisen. Are the methods of Undetermined Coefficients and approximating a polynomial using a polynomial closely related? When I say approximating a polynomial using a polynomial think of Newton's forward differences method.

Comment: "Are the methods of Undetermined Coefficients and approximating a polynomial using a polynomial closely related?" Yes, the interpolation polynomial is unique, and the method you get from undetermined coefficients is the one you get from interpolating a polynomial through $x_0, \dots, x_n$ and integrating it.